# Android studio logcat timestamps EDT time zone

Tags: android

I use Android Studio under Windows Server 2008R2

The time stamps in logcat are in EDT timezone.
So while my server's clock shows 5:40pm (UTC+1) the logcat time stamps show 11:40

Is there a way to configure Android Studio\logcat to display the server's local time ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?  I am running android studio on windows 7 and my logcat time stamps are in EDT while my system/device time is in IST.  I couldn't find any setting in android studio that would change the logcat time stamps to IST.

Answer (score 5):

Logcat uses Android device's time. Just set correct time on your device

Comment: i have same android device time and also my machine time then also the logcat time is different in Android Studio.... Problem still not resolved.

Comment: Same, changing device time appears to do nothing. Galaxy S8, AS 3.5

Comment: this is not  "the solution" but a bug imho, as multiple users describing this with device and machine having same time. I have ~5 AVD + physical all same time yet logcat prints some "fantasy time"

Answer (score 0):

Google assigned this bug report showing 6 different Android AVDs behaving, you guessed it, all different. One year old, no update. Please mark as affected if so:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193547255